# Selected drop down value is not being updated in the drop down menu in React when there is a function call in onChange()

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am working on a filter that will fetch the data from serviceNow depending on what the user has selected in the drop down menu. In my `onChange()`, I have a function call that will be filtering the data based on the value returned by `onChange()`. However, as soon as I put the function call(`handleFilter()`), the result is correctly fetched and displayed but the drop down menu selection is not updated.

Here is my drop down menu snippet

```
export default function DropDownComponent(props) {
  return (
    <div className="DropDownBox">
      <Select
        defaultValue={props.options[0]}
        isSearchable={false}
        name="DropDownBox"
        options={props.options}
        styles={dropDownStyles}
        autosize={false}
        onChange = {
          val => {
            props.changeDropdownValue(val);
            props.handleFilter(val)
          }
        }
      />
      <div className="caret_down_centered" />
    </div>
  );
```

> props.handleFilter(val) is the function call that prevents the updated in the drop down. If I remove this, then the drop down selection is updated but the whole functionality is rendered useless because there is no filtering being done.

`handleFilter(val)` is a parent class method & is simply invoking different API's depending upon what the value of `val` is which is passed from `onChange()`. I have no idea why it is interfering with the drop down menu.

I read that we can use a *state* and update the state everytime there is a change in selection but since I have a functional component, I am not sure how that will go.

I was not sure if handleFilter() code is needed here since it is a long code but if needed, then please let me know. I will post it here.

Comment: Please follow the following link: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/filtering/

Comment: I had come across that link. But as I said, I have a functional component and so there are not states. So, I cannot use a handler for updating the state on each change.

Comment: you can use Hook which works with functional component.

Comment: Actually, without the function, the changes are being reflected. So, that means that the changes are being automatically done. So, I was wondering what could be the root cause of the updates not being made just because of a simple function call that is just fetching data from the API. What might be the reason for the failure when the function has nothing to do with the drop down component.

Comment: it's working because you said already that full component re-rendered again which come up all the data from API which does not need function call anymore because filter data already in the component !

Comment: Can you please explain a bit in detail. I am still unable to understand why the choice is not being updated. Shouldn't it be updated almost instantaneously

Comment: I used the useState hook and it seems to be working fine. The only problem is that it is overriding the default value. Actually the state is set only in onChange() and this object is passed to "value". However, for the default case, the "defaultValue" attribute is overriden by this "value" which contains nothing as of now because onChange() is never triggered yet. So, I am getting "Select" as the default value whereas it should be an object that I had specified in the "defaultValue" prop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const DropDownComponent = props => { 
  return (
    <select
      name="selectFieldName"
      value={props.value}
      onChange={props.handleChange}
      // rest...
    >
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
    </select>
  )
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  // initial setup
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: 2 // Set your default value
    }
  }

  handleFilter = (value) => {
     // Here you fetch the data using 'value' argument
     console.log(value)
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    const value = e.target.value
    // update value
    this.setState({
      value // no need to write 'value' because both have the same name
    })
    // Call handleFilter passing selected "value"
    this.handleFilter(value)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Passing value and handleChange */}
        <DropDownComponent
          value={this.state.value}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <p>Value {this.state.value}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <Parent / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

I guess your problem is calling `handleFilter` method in wrong place. Also, you didn't tell how you have set the selected value inside the `handleFilter` method. See this [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-component-dropdown-menu-8yvk0) for example.